# How to pass variables into dynamic UIkit Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, modal-dialog, uikit

How do i pass variables into a UIkit Modal?

The Button:

```
<button type="button" class="uk-button" data-uk-modal="{target:'#info',center:true}" data-added="added-test" data-modified="modified-test"><i class="uk-icon-info"></i></button>
```

The Modal:

```
<div class="uk-modal" id="info">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <h4 style="margin-bottom:5px;">Added:</h4>
        <div id="added"></div><br>
        <h4 style="margin-bottom:5px;">Modified:</h4>    
        <div id="modified"></div>
        <div class="uk-modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="uk-button uk-modal-close">Close</button>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#info').on('uk.modal.show', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var added = button.data('added');
        var modified = $(e.target).data('modified');
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.uk-modal-dialog #added').text(added);
        modal.find('.uk-modal-dialog #modified').text(modified);
    });
});
```

This is not working. I do not get a error in the console. I´ve already tried a few other ways but all of them didn´t worked as they should.

**Update #1**

The following jquery works partially. I´ve added the id "infotrigger" to the button.

```
jQuery('#info').appendTo("body");
jQuery(document).on('click', '#infotrigger', infomodal_handler);
function infomodal_handler(e)
{
    var added = jQuery(e.target).data('added');
    var modified = jQuery(e.target).data('modified');
    jQuery('#info').on({
        'show.uk.modal':function(){
            jQuery('#added', jQuery(this)).text(added);
            jQuery('#modified', jQuery(this)).text(modified);
        }
    }).trigger('show.uk.modal');
}
```

The Problem now is that it´s only working partially. I think the reason is that the button is in a foreach loop. Mostly i have old data when opening the modal. If i open it again i have mostly the correct data.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that sometimes the icon was presssed instead of the button itself. So the data couldn´t be fetched. To fix this the variables need to be changed from:

```
var added = jQuery(e.target).data('added');
```

to:

```
var added = jQuery(this).data('added');
```

Now the correct dom element is the target.

To use the modal inside a loop i changed everything a bit. I´ve put the modal with the script into a function where i pass the element-id through and apply it to different elements:

```
function info_modal( $id ) {
    return "
    <script>
    jQuery('#info" . $id . "').appendTo('body');
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#infotrigger" . $id . "', infomodal_handler" . $id . ");
    function infomodal_handler" . $id . "(e)
    {
        console.log(e);
        var added" . $id . " = jQuery(this).data('added" . $id . "');
        var modified" . $id . " = jQuery(this).data('modified" . $id . "');
        jQuery('#info" . $id . "').on({
            'show.uk.modal':function(){
                jQuery('#added" . $id . "', jQuery(this)).text(added" . $id . ");
                jQuery('#modified" . $id . "', jQuery(this)).text(modified" . $id . ");
            }
        }).trigger('show.uk.modal');
    }
    </script>

    <!-- Info Modal -->
    <div class='uk-modal' id='info" . $id . "'>
        <div class='uk-modal-dialog'>
            <h4 style='margin-bottom:5px;'>" . __( 'Added on', 'easy-code-placement' ) . ":</h4>
            <div id='added" . $id . "'></div><br>
            <h4 style='margin-bottom:5px;'>" . __( 'Last Modified on', 'easy-code-placement' ) . ":</h4>    
            <div id='modified" . $id . "'></div>
            <div class='uk-modal-footer uk-text-right'>
              <button type='button' class='uk-button uk-modal-close'>" . __( 'Close', 'easy-code-placement' ) . "</button>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ";   
}
```

Inside the loop i´ve placed the button and also apply the element-id to it and after it i call the function (the function is only for the better code readability - the script and modal can, of course, also be placed directly inside the loop):

```
<button type="button" id="infotrigger<?php echo $code->id; ?>" class="uk-button" data-uk-modal="{target:'#info<?php echo $code->id; ?>',center:true}" data-added<?php echo $code->id; ?>="added" data-modified<?php echo $code->id; ?>="modified"><i class="uk-icon-info"></i></button>
<?php echo info_modal( $code->id ); ?>
```